# How do I add a wait period in AutoHotkey?

Tags: autohotkey

I have this script for a game

> ~Rbutton & M:: SendInput t You have the right to remain silent.
>   Anything you say can and will be used against you in the Supreme Court
>   of San Andreas, 2nd District.{enter} t As by the laws of San
>   Andreas,you have the right to speak to an attorney.{enter} t If you
>   cannot afford an attorney, one will be appointed for you.{enter} t Do
>   you understand these rights as they have been read to you?{enter}

I want my script to wait 2 seconds after each `enter` before sending the next line. How can I do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you mean to send a tab character, you need to change your `t` `` `t ``

So, change your code for the hotkey to read as a block instead of just a single line (do this by not putting the command all on one line, and by adding `return` at the end of it).  Then you can cause the 2 second delay with `sleep` (which uses milliseconds).

```
~Rbutton & M:: 
    SendInput, t You have the right to remain silent. Anything you say can and will be used against you in the Supreme Court of San Andreas, 2nd District.{enter} 
    sleep, 2000
    SendInput, t As by the laws of San Andreas,you have the right to speak to an attorney.{enter} t If you cannot afford an attorney, one will be appointed for you.{enter}
    sleep, 2000
    SendInput, t Do you understand these rights as they have been read to you?{enter}
return
```

Comment: @iramos, `\`t Do...` sends `{Tab}{Space}Do`, by the way (it's a common mistake, so just a tip).

Comment: I understand everyone thinks I meant for it to have a tab no I didn't it is actually meant to type "T"